# Random index with custom probability distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random, distribution

I have a vector of probabilities (which of course sum 1):

```
prob = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2]
```

Now I need to generate a random index for this vector (a number between 0 and 3 both included) but I want that the probability of each index is given by prob

```
0 will be generated with prob 0.1
1 will be generated with prob 0.3
2 will be generated with prob 0.4
3 will be generated with prob 0.2
```

I know that I can do this by calculating the cumsum

```
cumsum = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0]
```

Then generating a random number between 0 and 1:

```
rand_num = np.random.random()
```

And finally use `np.digitize` to check in which bin my random number falls.

```
idx = np.digitize([rand_num], cumsum)
```

This works and I'm happy with this, digitize even accepts a list of numbers and classifies them into the bins, so I can create my own function to generate indexes given a probability distribution.

My question is: This is a common problem, so doesn't a function already exist that does this? (And that will be more efficient than doing it myself)

Thanks

Comment: `prob.find(rand_num)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `random.choices` for this from Python 3.6, which includes a `weights` parameter:

```
>>> from random import choices
>>> prob = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2]
>>> choices(range(len(prob)), weights=prob)
[2]
>>> choices(range(len(prob)), weights=prob)
[3]
>>> choices(range(len(prob)), weights=prob, k=4)
[1, 2, 2, 2]
```